# What to do when snapshot.exists() returns false?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a ref that exists and I use `observeEventType` to query the data. But the ref might not have data in it due to the user deleting it. I test it using `snapshot.exists()`. In the situation below `snapshot.exists()` will return `false/no`. Since it's false I want to do something else but the code never runs

**How do I so something else when snapshot.exists() returns false/no?**

```
     //there is no data at levelTwo so there's nothing to observe
let levelTwoRef = dbRef.child("players").child("uid").child("levelTwo")

levelTwoRef.observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: {
        (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists(){
           if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String:AnyObject]{
              let power = dict["power"] as? String
              let score = dict["score"] as? String
           }
        //this will never run because the data has been deleted
        } else{
          do something else as an alternative //why isn't this running??
        }
    })
```

[image]

Comment: Update your question with your database JSON structure(actual, as text not an IMAGE!).

Comment: This is not your JSON structure, you get your JSON structure by clicking EXPORT JSON  in your firebase database console, minimise it to the most relevant parts and then post it.

Comment: @Dravidian You taught me something new. i never knew about that. I'll do it in a few. Thanks!

Comment: @Dravidian this is what i got back: {
  "error" : "Auth token is expired"
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase has a `.hasChild` function that you can run on a `child` to see if it exists:

```
func hasChild(_ childPathString: String) -> Bool
```

It takes a `child` as a `String` argument and returns `True` or `False` depending on wether it exists or not.

The way to check if a child exists is to first set a path to the child before the child your looking for. In the situation from the question the child to look for is `"levelTwo"` and the child before that is `uid`:

```
 //there is no data at levelTwo so there's nothing to observe
let levelTwoRef = dbRef.child("players").child("uid").child("levelTwo")
```

Assuming you know the *uid ref* definitely exists set a constant for the uid ref instead of the *levelTwo ref*

```
// uid path definitely exists
let uidRef = dbRef.child("players").child("uid")
```

Run `.value` on the *uid ref* and inside the callback check to see if the *levelTwo ref* exists:

```
uidRef?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {
                (snapshot) in

                if snapshot.hasChild("levelTwo"){
                     // true -levelTwo ref Does exist so do something
                }else{
                    // false -levelTwo ref DOESN'T exist so do something else
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running that inside observeEventType with the type `.ChildAdded`, which would return the snapshot of each new path that is created. If you just need to retrieve the value once you should use `observeSingleEventOfType` ([link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#/c:objc(cs)FIRDatabaseReference(im)observeSingleEventOfType:withBlock:)), with `.Value` as the event type.

Comment: thanks. 2 things. 1- I tried observeSingleEventOfType and since there was nothing there my else statement didn't run . 2- There are going to be multiple paths under the node. .Value takes a snapshot of all everything at once from the node. .ChildAdded makes multiple trips to get everything under the node. You get the same results in either case. That's not my issue. My issue what to do when there isn't anything there at all.